# first time getting undefined props from mapStateToProps

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, reducers, redux-actions

how can i get asynchronous reducers data ,i search but didn't get solution
**Booking** component

```
    cutPick = () => {

            this.props.pickup(false);

        }
```

**action** creator

```
export function pickup(latlng) {

    return function (dispatch) {

        dispatch({type:PICKUP_STATE,payload:latlng});
    }

}
```

**reducer**

```
import {PICKUP_STATE} from '../actions/types';

export default function (state={},action) {

    switch(action.type) {
        case PICKUP_STATE:

            return {...state,pickup:action.payload}
    }
    return state;
}
```

**Map** component

```
import React from 'react';
import scriptLoader from "react-async-script-loader";
import config from '../../../config'
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import {  Icon,Button,Alert,Row, Col} from 'antd';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../actions";

class Map extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pick:false,
            drop:false,
            mapCenter : { lat: 17.3850, lng: 78.4867 },
            pickupConfirmButton:false,
            dropoffConfirmButton:false
        };
        this.map=false;
        this.directionsService =false;
        this.directionsDisplay = false;
        this.mapLoaded = false;
        this.pickMarker=false;
        this.dropMarker=false;
    }

    //listen map current location event and set marker and pick state
    addYourLocationButton = (map) => {

            this.pickMarker = new google.maps.Marker   ({
                map: this.map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                position: this.state.pick ? this.state.pick : this.state.mapCenter,
                draggable: true
            });

        if(!this.mapLoaded) {
            return false;
        }
        var controlDiv = document.createElement('div');

        let firstChild = document.createElement('button');
        firstChild.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
        firstChild.style.border = 'none';
        firstChild.style.outline = 'none';
        firstChild.style.width = '28px';
        firstChild.style.height = '28px';
        firstChild.style.borderRadius = '2px';
        firstChild.style.boxShadow = '0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)';
        firstChild.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        firstChild.style.marginRight = '10px';
        firstChild.style.padding = '0px';
        firstChild.title = 'Your Location';
        controlDiv.appendChild(firstChild);

        let secondChild = document.createElement('div');
        secondChild.style.margin = '5px';
        secondChild.style.width = '18px';
        secondChild.style.height = '18px';
        secondChild.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://maps.gstatic.com/tactile/mylocation/mylocation-sprite-1x.png)';
        secondChild.style.backgroundSize = '180px 18px';
        secondChild.style.backgroundPosition = '0px 0px';
        secondChild.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
        secondChild.id = 'you_location_img';
        firstChild.appendChild(secondChild);

        // google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend',  () => {
        //     document.getElementById("you_location_img").style.backgroundPosition='0px 0px';
        // });
        google.maps.event.addListener(this.pickMarker, 'dragend', () =>{

            let lat=this.pickMarker.getPosition().lat();
            let lng=this.pickMarker.getPosition().lng();

            this.setState({pick:{lat:lat,lng:lng}},function () {
                let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
                geocoder.geocode({'location': {lat:lat,lng:lng}}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status === 'OK') {
                        document.getElementById('pick').value = results[0].formatted_address;
                    }
                })
                // console.log(this.state.pick);
            })
            if (this.state.pick && this.state.drop){
                this.calculateRoute();
            }
        });
        firstChild.addEventListener('click',  () => {
            let imgX = '0';
            let animationInterval = setInterval( () =>{
                if (imgX == '-18') imgX = '0';
                else imgX = '-18';
                document.getElementById("you_location_img").style.backgroundPosition=imgX + 'px 0px';
            }, 500);

            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( (position) => {
                    let latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                    let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
                    geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
                        if (status === 'OK') {
                            document.getElementById('pick').value = results[0].formatted_address;
                        }
                    })
                    if(latlng){
                        this.setState(()=>({
                            pick:latlng
                        }))
                    }
                    this.pickMarker.setPosition(latlng);
                    map.setCenter(latlng);
                    if (this.state.pick && this.state.drop){
                        this.calculateRoute();
                    }

                    clearInterval(animationInterval);
                    document.getElementById("you_location_img").style.backgroundPosition='-144px 0px';
                });
            }
            else {
                clearInterval(animationInterval);
                document.getElementById("you_location_img").style.backgroundPosition='0px 0px';
            }
        });

        controlDiv.index = 1;
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(controlDiv);
    }

    //load gmaps ,load maps and directions and set center as user current location
    componentWillReceiveProps({isScriptLoadSucceed}){
        if (isScriptLoadSucceed) {
            this.mapLoaded= true;
            this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ suppressMarkers: true });


            this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 11,
                center: this.state.mapCenter
            });
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( (position)=> {
                    let initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                    // console.log(this.state.mapCenter)

                    this.setState({mapCenter:initialLocation} , ()=> {
                        // console.log(this.state.mapCenter)
                    })
                    this.map.setCenter(initialLocation);
                });
            }else{
                console.log('error in current location')
            }

            this.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.map);

            //icon of current location in map and current loc pickup marker
            this.addYourLocationButton(this.map);

            //listener for pickup marker when it clicked
            this.pickMarker.addListener('click', () =>{
                this.pickupMarkerClickListener();
            });

        }
        else{
            alert("Something went wrong, plz check internet Connection")
        }
    }
    //for Refs
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.onRef(this);
    }
    //for Refs
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.props.onRef(null);
    }


    // this function pick state false when user click on cut pick address from pickup field and set direction false also
    isPickEmpty=(emptyPickState)=>{

        console.log(this.props.pickupProps);
        this.setState({pick:emptyPickState},function () {
            this.pickMarker.setMap(null);
            this.directionsDisplay.set('directions', null);
            //sending false as distance to BookingDetails
            this.props.routeCalc(false);
        });

    };

    //it handle search hint of google place api (getting data from Booking Form)
    pickupSearch =(pickupAddress) =>{
        let options = {
            types: [],
            componentRestrictions: {
                'country': 'IN'
            }
        };
        let inputPick = document.getElementById('pick');
        const autocompletePick = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputPick, options);
        autocompletePick.bindTo('bounds', this.map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocompletePick, 'place_changed',  () => {
            let place =autocompletePick.getPlace();
            let lat = place.geometry.location.lat(),
                lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
            let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
            geocoder.geocode({'location': {lat:lat,lng:lng}}, function(results, status) {
                if (status === 'OK') {
                    document.getElementById('pick').value = results[0].formatted_address;
                }
            });
            this.pickUp({lat:lat,lng:lng})
        });
    }

    //this function put pick marker on pickup search
    pickUp = (pick) => {
        // console.log(pick)
        if(this.pickMarker){
            this.pickMarker.setMap(null);
        }

        this.setState({pick:pick}, () => {
            // console.log(this.state.pick);
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
            this.pickMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map:this.map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                position: this.state.pick,
                draggable: true
            });
            infoWindow.setPosition(this.state.pick);
            // infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
            // infoWindow.open(this.map);
            this.map.setCenter(this.state.pick);

            this.pickMarker.addListener('click', () =>{
                this.pickupMarkerClickListener();
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(this.pickMarker, 'dragend', () =>{
                this.pickupMarkerDragListener();

            });
            this.focus.scrollIntoView();
        })
        if (this.state.pick && this.state.drop){
            this.calculateRoute();
        }
    };

    //this function invoke click and drag function of pickup marker
    pickupMaker=()=>{

        this.setState({pickupConfirmButton:false});
        this.map.setZoom(11);
        if(this.pickMarker){
            this.pickMarker.setMap(null);
        }

        google.maps.event.clearListeners(this.map, 'center_changed');

        this.pickMarker = new google.maps.Marker   ({
            map: this.map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: this.state.pick,
            draggable:true
        });

        if(this.dropMarker){
            this.dropMarker.setVisible(true);
        }

        //listening on drag of pick marker
        google.maps.event.addListener(this.pickMarker, 'dragend', () => {
            this.pickupMarkerDragListener();
            console.log('marker')

        });

        //listening on click of pick marker
        this.pickMarker.addListener('click', () =>{
            this.pickupMarkerClickListener();
        });

        //if both state are set the calculate the root
        if (this.state.pick && this.state.drop){
            this.calculateRoute();
        }
    };

    //this function handle click event of pick Marker
    pickupMarkerClickListener = () => {
        if(this.dropMarker){
            this.dropMarker.setVisible(false);
        }
        this.directionsDisplay.set('directions', null);
        this.setState({pickupConfirmButton:true});
        this.map.setCenter(this.pickMarker.getPosition());
        this.map.setZoom(16);

        this.map.addListener('center_changed',  () => {
            let lat=this.map.getCenter().lat();
            let lng=this.map.getCenter().lng();

            this.setState({pick:{lat:lat,lng:lng}},function () {
                let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
                geocoder.geocode({'location': {lat:lat,lng:lng}}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status === 'OK') {
                        document.getElementById('pick').value = results[0].formatted_address;
                    }
                })
                // console.log(this.state.pick);
            });
            this.pickMarker.setPosition({lat:lat,lng:lng});
            // console.log(this.map.getCenter().lat(),this.map.getCenter().lng(),this.pickMarker.getPosition())

        });
    };

    //This function Handle drage event of pick marker
    pickupMarkerDragListener = () => {
        console.log('dragged');
        let lat=this.pickMarker.getPosition().lat();
        let lng=this.pickMarker.getPosition().lng();

        this.setState({pick:{lat:lat,lng:lng}}, () => {
            let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
            geocoder.geocode({'location': {lat:lat,lng:lng}}, (results, status) => {
                if (status === 'OK') {
                    document.getElementById('pick').value = results[0].formatted_address;
                }
            })
            console.log(this.state.pick);
        })
        if ((this.state.pick && this.state.drop) && (this.state.pickupConfirmButton === false && this.state.dropoffConfirmButton ===false)){
            this.calculateRoute();
        }
    }


    // this function drop state false when user click on cut drop address from dropoff field and set direction false also
    isDropEmpty=(emptyDropState)=>{
        // console.log(emptyPickState);
        // console.log(this.state.pick);
        this.setState({drop:emptyDropState},function () {
            // this.pickMarker=false;
            this.dropMarker.setMap(null);
            this.directionsDisplay.set('directions', null);
            //sending false as distance to BookingDetails
            this.props.routeCalc(false);
        });

    };

    //it handle drop search hint of google place api (getting data from Booking Form)
    dropoffSearch = (dropoffSearch) =>{
        let options = {
            types: [],
            componentRestrictions: {
                'country': 'IN'
            }
        };

        const autocompleteDrop = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('drop'), options);
        autocompleteDrop.bindTo('bounds', this.map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocompleteDrop, 'place_changed',  () => {
            let place =autocompleteDrop.getPlace();
            let lat = place.geometry.location.lat(),
                lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
            // this.props.dropHandler({lat:lat,lng:lng})
            //
            // this.setState({drop:place.name});
            // let lat = place.geometry.location.lat(),
            //     lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
            //putting place in pick field
            let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
            geocoder.geocode({'location': {lat:lat,lng:lng}}, function(results, status) {
                if (status === 'OK') {
                    // console.log(results[0].formatted_address)
                    document.getElementById('drop').value = results[0].formatted_address;
                }
            });
            this.dropOff({lat:lat,lng:lng})
        });
    };

    //this function put drop marker on dropoff search(function invoked from Booking Details)
    dropOff = (drop) => {
        if (this.dropMarker){
            this.dropMarker.setMap(null);
        }
        this.setState({drop:drop}, () => {
            // console.log(this.state.drop);
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
            this.dropMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map:this.map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                position: this.state.drop,
                draggable: true
            });
            infoWindow.setPosition(this.state.drop);
            // infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
            // infoWindow.open(this.map);
            this.map.setCenter(this.state.drop);
            // console.log(this.state.drop);
            google.maps.event.addListener(this.dropMarker, 'dragend', () =>{

                this.dropoffMarkerDragListener();


            });
            this.dropMarker.addListener('click', () =>{
                this.dropoffMarkerClickListener();
            });

            if (this.state.pick && this.state.drop){
                this.calculateRoute();
            }
            this.focus.scrollIntoView();
        })

        // if (this.state.pick && this.state.drop){
        //     this.calculateRoute();
        // }
    };

    //this function invoke click and drag function of drop marker
    dropoffMaker= () =>{
        this.setState({dropoffConfirmButton:false});
        this.map.setZoom(11);
        this.dropMarker.setMap(null);
        google.maps.event.clearListeners(this.map, 'center_changed');

        this.dropMarker = new google.maps.Marker   ({
            map: this.map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: this.state.drop,
            draggable: true
        });
        if(this.pickMarker){
            this.pickMarker.setVisible(true);
        }

        google.maps.event.addListener(this.dropMarker, 'dragend', () =>{
            this.dropoffMarkerDragListener();

        });
        this.dropMarker.addListener('click', () =>{
            this.dropoffMarkerClickListener();
        });

        if (this.state.pick && this.state.drop){
            this.calculateRoute();
        }
    }

    //this function handle click event of Drop Marker
    dropoffMarkerClickListener=()=>{
        this.pickMarker.setVisible(false);
        this.directionsDisplay.set('directions', null);
        this.setState({dropoffConfirmButton:true});
        this.map.setCenter(this.dropMarker.getPosition());
        this.map.setZoom(16);
        this.map.addListener('center_changed',  () => {
            let lat=this.map.getCenter().lat();
            let lng=this.map.getCenter().lng();

            this.setState({drop:{lat:lat,lng:lng}},function () {
                let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
                geocoder.geocode({'location': {lat:lat,lng:lng}}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status === 'OK') {
                        document.getElementById('drop').value = results[0].formatted_address;
                    }
                });
            });
            this.dropMarker.setPosition({lat:lat,lng:lng});
            console.log(this.map.getCenter().lat(),this.map.getCenter().lng(),this.dropMarker.getPosition())

        });
    }

    //This function Handle drage event of drop marker
    dropoffMarkerDragListener= () => {
        let lat=this.dropMarker.getPosition().lat();
        let lng=this.dropMarker.getPosition().lng();

        this.setState({drop:{lat:lat,lng:lng}},function () {
            let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
            geocoder.geocode({'location': {lat:lat,lng:lng}}, function(results, status) {
                if (status === 'OK') {
                    document.getElementById('drop').value = results[0].formatted_address;
                }
            })
            console.log(this.state.drop);
        })
        if ((this.state.pick && this.state.drop) && (this.state.pickupConfirmButton === false && this.state.dropoffConfirmButton ===false)){
            this.calculateRoute();
        }
    };

    //this function set direction and calculate the root of pick and drop
    calculateRoute = () =>{
        var request ={
            origin:this.state.pick,
            destination:this.state.drop,
            travelMode:"DRIVING"
        };
        this.directionsService.route(request,(result,status) => {
            if(status== "OK"){
                console.log(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance);
                this.props.routeCalc(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance);
                this.directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
            }
        });
    };


    render(){

        return(
            <div className="Map" ref={node => this.focus = node}>

                    <Alert
                        message="Tap or Drag Marker[s] to set exact location Then Click on Confirm Location"
                        type="info"
                        showIcon
                    />
                    <div id="map" style={{height: "500px"}}></div>
                    {this.state.pickupConfirmButton && <Button  className="cnfrmBtn"  size="large" onClick={this.pickupMaker}>Confirm Location</Button> }
                    {this.state.dropoffConfirmButton && <Button className="cnfrmBtn" size="large" onClick={this.dropoffMaker}>Confirm Location</Button> }

            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
    return {pickupProps:state.BookingData.pickup}
}
// export default Map;
const ScriptLoadedMap = scriptLoader(
    [config.MapApi]
)(Map);
export default connect(mapStateToProps,actions)(ScriptLoadedMap);
```

**i'm sending false value from *Booking* to action creator then i'm dispatching and storing value in *action* in reducer**

but when i'm calling **pickupProps** from **Map** component first time i'm getting **undefined** after first time getting **false** value.
so here my problem is how can i get first time (asynchronous) false value when it called from **Booking** component.

Comment: can you console.log(state.BookingData.pickup) in your mapStateToProps to see if it is being called?

Comment: @miles_christian getting **false** value

Comment: how can i get in my component function

Comment: Ok I see now what you mean.  Try connecting your map compnent to redux then pass that connected component to your script loader.  See this [example](https://gist.github.com/robinmonjo/2790fb319351843349cfec43213f4898)

Comment: @miles_christian i think that's not the problem,because when i'm second time invoking that function it console the **value**

Comment: can you post your Map component code?

Comment: @miles_christian i edited the code

Comment: I don't see where you are calling isPickEmpty(), but remember any state update made by mapStateToProps only becomes valid on the next render of the component.  So probably when you check the value for the first time the component has not re-rendered yet.

Comment: first thing is i'm calling function using **ref** in another component.second thing is **how can i get mapStateToProps state before next rendering** that's the problem.i know that we can't get state before rendering.is there any way i can access that state.

Comment: i'm sending value to redux reducer state from Booking component, same time i'm calling function of Map component using ref so in Map component i want to fetch redux reducer state,then i'm using MapStateToProps function to fetch value. so my problem is Map component didn't render so i'm unable to access MapStateToProps(props value) inside my class function, when i'm using inside render() i'm able to access those props.so is there any way to access redux props inside class function where componet didn't re-render() first time.

Comment: Ok got it. Either make the state a parameter of the function then call it from somewhere with access to the state, passing the state in. Usually most async libraries have access to the store and you can call store.getState() to get the latest state.  But in fact I made an enchancer [redux-named-reducers](https://github.com/mileschristian/redux-named-reducers) to allow me to access state from anywhere also with something like getState(module.externalSate) it helps keep code modularized. You can try it as an alternative.

Comment: @miles_christian can u do me favor, when i call `this.props.pickup(emptyPickState);`  from **Map** component then it calling action creator where it **dispatch** to reducer, **how can i render my component,when reducer state is update**. you can check **reducer** and **action creator** from above code.