# how can i get mapStateToProps props in class function

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, reducers

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
    return {pickupProps:state.BookingData.pickup}
}
// export default Map;
const ScriptLoadedMap = scriptLoader(
    [config.MapApi]
)(Map);
export default connect(mapStateToProps,actions)(ScriptLoadedMap);
```

here i want to access **pickupProps**.when i was consoling inside render i'm getting props value but when i'm calling inside any class function **first time** i'm getting **undefined** value.
i think here state is not updating so component was not re-rendering.

```
isPickEmpty=(emptyPickState)=>{

    console.log(this.props.pickupProps);

};
```

**here how can i access pickupProps**
reminder one thing is that i can access pickupProps second time when i invoke function 
please help me.i'm stuckkkkkkkkk!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'getDerivedStateFromProps' to update the state, and then use the state inside the methods. 
 Also, did you bind the method in the cunstructor? And did you try accessing the props in the 'componentDidMount' method?

Comment: i'm sending value to **redux reducer state** from **Booking** component, same time i'm calling function of **Map** component using **ref** so in **Map** component i want to fetch **redux reducer state**,then i'm using MapStateToProps function to fetch value. so my problem is **Map** component didn't render so i'm unable to access MapStateToProps(props value) inside my class function, when i'm using inside render() i'm able to access those props.so is there any way to access redux props inside class function where componet didn't re-render() first time.

Comment: First of all, you should upload more of your code because it's difficult to understand what exactly is going on from your description. 
The props from `mapStateToProps` aren't set at the `render` method, so there shouldn't be a necessity to wait for the component to render in order to access them. 
So to set things straight: `mapStateToProps` is setting the props when a component is constructed, so if you fail to get to them to problem probably lies elsewhere.  For example, if you were using `this` inside a function but hadn't bind the context to that function. Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50406252/first-time-getting-undefined-props-from-mapstatetoprops?noredirect=1#comment87899049_50406252

Comment: yes, i bind all functions and it not consoling the **value** first time in componentDidMount,because it not re-rendering

Comment: Again, rerendering has nothing to do with it. `mapStateToProps` is called before your component is initialized! Your code doesn't show where `isPickEmpty` is called, nor does it show you bind it to the context at any point.

Comment: i told u that `isPickEmpty` called from another component using `ref`. second thing is i already install package in babel so don't need to bind function. in my whole project i didn't bind the function. i used arrow function.

Comment: I didn't get that at first, now things make more sense. Well, care to explain why you are calling a method of one component from another? Could be that Map is not initialized at all when you call the method, and therefore has no props whatsoever. Communication between components should be done through redux. so in your case, why not having the pick fire an action in your `Map`, and then check for changes in `booking`?

Comment: ok, now if we take like this,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50448316/how-to-get-mapstatetoprops-value-in-class-function

Comment: i just change the flow for better explanation